# Combining microkernel pattern with microservices?

Tags: design-patterns, kubernetes, microservices, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I currently have a monolithic server application that provides some workforce management workflow features. This monolith is getting unwieldy, and I'd like to split it up and make it more modular. I'm thinking about potentially creating microservice containers on Kubernetes, but I also like the idea of using a microkernel plugin architecture so that the core platform doesn't have to hard-code every feature. A Pub/Sub event bus helps with some of that, but I also need to be able to make direct invocation calls (e.g., REST or gRPC) in some of the workflows.

Are there any effective patterns which combine the microservice pattern with the microkernel plugin pattern? Perhaps maybe using configuration files to define various workflow hooks?

Comment: I'm confused about the phrase, "_RPC-style calls e.g., REST_". REST is not an example of RPC. REST and RPC are opposing architectures. Perhaps you meant to say, "_HTTP calls e.g., REST or gRPC_"?

Comment: Yes. I meant to use a generic term for direct invocation.

Comment: I was experimenting with something similar, and started using a discovery mechanism to let components discover each other based on services they implement. My purpose was to minimize configuration in a plugin based architecture. Maybe it can give you some ideas. It is explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57815832/multiple-services-for-same-appport-in-kubernetes

Comment: @bserdar So basically you use the Kubernetes API server as a service discovery system using meta data app labels? I think I might be looking for something more granular, with potential priority ordering of hooks. Also I'm not sure I want to couple my application code to Kubernetes, that is, to query Kubernetes resource metadata.

Comment: Perhaps the [Template design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method) along with plain Microservices structure would fit your needs.